# EXCEL VBA How to pass date from input box into Days Formula?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem regarding passing a date into a formula .

Could you please help me out ?

```
Dim DueDate As String

DueDate = InputBox("Esedékesség Dátuma ?")

Range("N1").Value = "Hátramaradó napok száma esedékességik"

Range("N2").Select

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=DAYS(RC[-11],""DueDate"")*(-1)"
Range("N2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("N2:N3000")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have it, it will enter text "DueDate" into the formula. You need to tell the vba to use DueDate as variable and then you need to make sure it understands it is a date. Something like

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=DAYS(RC[-11],DATEVALUE(""" & DueDate & """))*(-1)"
```